# Is it possible to mix jetpack compose with components that are not available in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am starting with Jetpack compose for android. I like it so far. I am a bit skeptical of starting a new project with it, though. I know not all types of views are available on Jetpack.
 For example I would like to use 3rd party libraries to render graphs in the app. But, these libraries are provide you the traditional views that you either inflate programatically or use it `xml`. Is it possible to have some views defined in `xml` while some from compose? Is jetpack compose mature enough to start using in production applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use xml widgets inside your compose views, you can use the composable [`AndroidView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#AndroidView(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)) for that:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        TextView(context)
    }
)
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose) on Views in Compose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jetpack Compose is ready to use in Android. Whether to use it or not is a question about your experience :)
There are some non-intuitive behaviours like read-defer lambdas, so You must be aware of them before start.
A lot of top high-tech companies already use it.

I don't understand what do You mean in "3rd party libraries to render graphics", maybe You mean some custom libraries for UI like Charts? If Yes, then You will have Activity with Fragments with UI on xml and use Jetpack Compose views being injected into xml layout. That's how developers integrate Compose in existing xml-based applications.